# Scala Play 2.5 Action composition with Deadbolt-2 actions

Tags: scala, playframework, deadbolt-2

I'm working on a Scala Play application and need many Controller actions disabling caching of the browser by setting parameters in the HTTP headers of the Response. I decided to create a `NoCache` composite action and since I am also using Deadbolt-2 (and need a Deadbolt-2's `AuthenticatedRequest[_]`) it looks like this:

```
package action

import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.AuthenticatedRequest
import play.api.http.HeaderNames
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.Success

case class NoCache[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] with HeaderNames {
  def apply(request: AuthenticatedRequest[A]): Future[Result] = {
    action(request).andThen {
      case Success(result) => result.withHeaders(
        (CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"),
        (PRAGMA -> "no-cache"),
        (EXPIRES -> "0")
      )
    }
  }

  lazy val parser = action.parser
}
```

but then it won't compile trying to mix in this Action into my Controller action implementations e.g.

```
def link = deadbolt.SubjectPresent()() andThen NoCache() { implicit request =>
```

or

```
def link = NoCache(deadbolt.SubjectPresent()()) { implicit request =>
```

but can't see how to compose them ...

Comment: Did you find a solution? Im having the same issue composing Play Actions with DeadboltActions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it for a single action:

```
def index = NoCache {
  deadbolt.WithAuthRequest()() { implicit request =>
    Future {
      Ok(views.html.index(userService))
    }
  }
}
```

However, I still haven't found how to apply `NoCache` to the entire controller class.